# CUDA out of memory Dreambooth

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

A few days ago I ran this known [DreamBooth Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/sd_dreambooth_training.ipynb) with my face and I was able to get some results. But yesterday I wanted to retrain it again to make it better (tried using the same photos again), and right now, it throws this out of memory exception:

[image: image.png]

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1024.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 12.24 GiB already allocated; 501.75 MiB free; 13.16 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I was wondering if someone had the same problem and know  why is this happening now and not before.
I'm linking [my colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f8rJxx2pOsXQzsVVZDovAsNHaw6So7cf) to show it to you.

Comment: Please do **not** post code/error screenshots; see how to create a [mre].

Comment: where you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve just reduced the resolution and was able to run it.

Go to

> Setting up all training args

And change

`resolution=512`

to

`resolution=256`

Sure, you´ll loose quality. But at least it works with the free colab version.

UPDATE: just tried with 480 and works as well. Just be sure to restart the environment to free the GPU memory first.